# Best way to exclude your Android app from being downloaded by old/slow devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I know you can remove selected devices from distribution. While I'm not sure what is the good indicator to limit slow devices. One idea is to exclude all 32 bit only CPUs. While I think there could be fairly performant 32 bit CPUs out there. Therefore I'm not sure if I should limit all 32 bit CPUs.

On the other hand may be there are not many active Android users with 32 bit CPUs at all - so I should not worry about excluding them all.

Also it seems that the new Google Play console doesn't allow you to exclude devices by rule. You need to go and manually select every single device you want to exclude. There are thousands of Android devices...

Comment: up your minimum SDK level to something super recent like Q :-) then perhaps combine that with only `xhdpi` devices and over https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Comment: yeah, I think screen resolution is actually quite good indicator - also may be amount of RAM